# Lenovo Ideapad y700 shift key doesn't repeat

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I was gonna play some games on my new laptop when I discovered that my shift key doesn't repeat. I have been looking around in the Ease of Access Center but can't find a way to turn it on. I already have filtered keys turned off and the other keys are repeating as they should (except for some other modifier keys like <kbd>CTRL</kbd>).

I probably have to change something in the registry but I can't find out what.

Comment: Shift key does not repeat means what??

Comment: Disable sticky key mode.

Comment: Sometimes you have to hit the key multiple times in rapid succession to wake the key up.  In windows this can bring up the disabled-person access control item.

Comment: @RakibulIslam when you hold a button and it keeps spamming it, this works for most of my buttons except for shift.

Comment: @Ramhound it's already disabled

Comment: @wendy.krieger i tried it but it doesn't seem to work. It also doesn't bring up anything.